# How to Redirect from one view to another view with data - Yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

i want to pass 1 variables from a view to another view with post method. use this redirect code but its not working

```
 Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect('home','id'=>$id)->send();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect(['home','id' => $id])->send();
```

Comment: you cant pass post param via redirect, you can build and submit a form via JavaScript.

Comment: or you can save param in the session and read in the new page

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness in a controller context you may use:

```
class MyController extends \yii\web\Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->redirect(['home', 'id' => 123]);
    }
}
```

Where the array parameter of `redirect()` is equal to [yii\helpers\Url::to()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#to()-detail).